# What is better, single endpoint but multiple db query or multiple endpoint with single db query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, redux

When my app loads, I will get the data from server (express) and place the result to redux (my global state). What I have now is multiple endpoint like this:

- api/get/hmo
- api/get/groups
- api/get/items
- api/get/papers

each has a normal select db query.

Is there will be a downside if I will make it a single endpoint and make a multiple select and return it to client all at once like this:

- api/get/allData

and inside my controller something like:

```
const hmo = Select * from hmo;
const groups = Select * from groups;
const items = Select * from items;
const papers = Select * from papers;

return res.send(200).json({
   hmo,
   groups,
   items,
   papers
})
```

What is the best practice and which is faster on the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### for faster

Let's calculate resources consume in each solution.
[image]
it seems `solution 2` consume less resources, and is faster than solution 1. solution 2 saves some http connections and db connections.

### for best practice

but it may not be the best practice. because efficiency is not the only thing we should consider when design(or develop) an application. here are some examples for you.

- users visiting your website will get first data(eg: hmo) fastly in solution 1. the 4 data your request may not be as important as each other.
- your apis will reusable in other modules or clients(eg: mobile app) if you seperate them.

so it depends, you should consider more than `faster` to design your api.

Answer (score 0):

Do both, and let the client choose what works best for them.

Best practice is to have simple, fine-grained APIs; as many as you need/want.

The all-in-one API is a course-grained *facade* that is a thin layer that groups up the fine-grained ones.

Ideally, facades are not part of the fine-grained server’s API, but rather exist on a server local to it. This is because facades tend to change, eg you might add yet another fine-grained API to the group or add query parameters etc, but the fine-grained APIs, being simple, tend to also be stable, so you only deploy what’s changing. Also, they don’t need to be all on the same server for the facade to group them up (in fact, you can get a performance boost by putting the fine-grained API each on their own server to distribute processing load).

In your case, you can just put it all on the same server and see how it goes. If it works well, you can always carve it off into a new facade server.